# How to Revert Public Git Repo to Specific Previous Commit?

Tags: git, repository, git-revert

I want to revert a public repo I recently cloned back to a previous version of itself from a year ago. I don't want to do a hard revert.

I have already tried this:

```
cd MyRepo
git revert --no-commit dc3b4359..
```

But I got this error:

```
error: could not revert dc3b4359...
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
```

I am a novice at this; what code could be used to do this safely? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by a "hard revert"? What should happen to the files in the repository, what should happen to the history?

Comment: This is not an error. This is a [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git). But as a sidenote, reverting a ton of commits like that seems an unnecessary burden. Why did you rule out a hard reset (I guess you meant hard reset since hard revert is meaningless)

Comment: You tried to revert a single commit. Git does this by appending change, which is the opposite of dc3b4359. That change is conflicting with other commits that happened after.

Comment: @StijnHaezebrouck The general point about the behaviour of `revert` is correct but OP's command is not reverting a *single* commit. It reverts a whole range (mind the double dots).

Comment: @RomainValeri you are correct of course, overlooked those

Answer (score 0):

**(EDITED)** (thanks @torek)

The most crude way would be:

```
cd MyRepo
git rm -r .
git checkout dc3b4359 -- .
git add .
git commit -m "Going back in time"
git push origin master
```

Original answer:

```
cd MyRepo
rm -rf * # if you have files starting with '.', delete them too.
git checkout dc3b4359 -- .
git add .
git commit -m "Going back in time"
```

Comment: Sometimes better to use `git rm` so that you don't disturb untracked files, but yes, that method will work in the local repo; OP will then need to `git push` the resulting commit.